# gitlab react docker: npm not found

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, gitlab, dockerfile, pipeline

I am trying to get myself up and running with Gitlab, so I may have misunderstood some concepts. My goal is to setup a continuous integration pipeline where a docker image is built (and eventually deployed, at the moment it is just the build)

1. I have created a simple hello-world app with create-react-app.
2. I have created an account on Gitlab and a repository for my project
3. I have added a `.gitlab-ci.yml` to enable continuous integration
   (I would like to use a `shared gitlab-runner`)
4. I have added a dockerfile to my project to build an image.

Here is the content of my `gitlab-ci.yml` file:
[image]

And here is the content of my dockerfile:

[image]

Then when I push a commit the my gitlab repo, the CI pipeline starts and 
attends to run my scripts.

But it fails with this error:

[image]

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong so that npm is not found. 
Is there an error in my `.yml` file or the `dockerfile` or both?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: alpine:latest probably doesn't have npm insalled. try to use different base image, maybe alpine-node will do the trick

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is the error I am getting now:
Error: image library/alpine-node:latest not found

Comment: try: node:alpine (or any specific version from: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ )

Comment: I was able to get it running to using this node:11.4.0-alpine and by adding git and ssh in my docker (see https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/586)

Answer (score 0):

npm is not installed in alpine:latest. you can install the relevant dependencies in your own image that uses alpine:latest or just use node:alpine which comes with npm, node and yarn

Comment: I am using node:11.4.0-alpine and that error seems to have gone

Answer (score 0):

Your `alpine` image does not contain node. You have to install node for the `alpine` image. But better solution is using an appropriate `node` image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) rather than using `alpine` image.